# Gef BendPoints That are curved

Tags: eclipse-gef

Hi is there an possiblity of drawing gef connections with curved bendpoints . ie the bend points must be rounded . if yes please post in how that can be achieved

Answer (score 1):

From what I know neither `GEF` nor `draw2d` implement this (although I may be wrong but a thorough Google did not provide an answer).
You can check the implementation provided in `org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.draw2d.ui.figures.PolylineConnectionEx` (part of the GMF framework) which does rounded corners.